# What is a student called that completed high school and is about to start college/uni?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call a student who has completed year 12/senior year of high school and are about to begin 1st year/freshman year of uni/college but have not started yet? Happy for both US and UK versions.

Research: There seem to be a few US specific terms for this but I haven't been able to find a UK equivalent, if someone with more knowledge of the UK education system could clarify this that would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no single word that covers all these conditions. If you think you’ve found one, please share.

Comment: "Incoming freshman" seems to be this in the US as per the previous comments which have now been deleted for some reason?

Comment: It depends on what educational system you're asking about. Different places have different names.